How can I create a new log file monthly in symfony 5.4?
i'd like to rotate my log file monthly in symfony, meaning, i'd like to have a new log file for each month of the year, is this possible with symfony? how can i achieve this?
this is my current log configuration in monolog.yaml:
when@dev:
    monolog:
        handlers:
            main:
                type: rotating_file
                path: "%kernel.logs_dir%/%kernel.environment%.log"
                level: debug
                channels: ["!event"]
            # uncomment to get logging in your browser
            # you may have to allow bigger header sizes in your Web server configuration
            #firephp:
            #    type: firephp
            #    level: info
            #chromephp:
            #    type: chromephp
            #    level: info
            console:
                type: console
                process_psr_3_messages: false
                channels: ["!event", "!doctrine", "!console"]

I'm trying to use
type:  rotating_file
but i dont know how to make this rotation monthly

Consider an external tool, e.g. https://linux.die.net/man/8/logrotate
